# Covering numbers

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to prove the following claim:
for any $A \subseteq R^m$, scalar $c>0$ and vector $v_0 \in R^m$ we have: 
$\forall r>0  , $ $ N(r,\{ca + v_0 : a\in A\}) \leq N(cr,A)  $

where $N(r,A)$  is the cardinality of the smallest set that $r-covers$ $A$

I tried to prove that if $A'$ is a $cr-cover$ of $A$ then it must be a $r-cover$ of the set $ \{ca + v_0 : a\in A\} $, but I couldn't prove it.

Any other ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement you tried to prove is wrong, but you are on the right track.
Try proving instead that if $A'$ is a $cr$-cover of $A$, then $\{ca'+v_0 : a' \in A\}$ is an $r$-cover of $\{ca+v_0 : a \in A\}$.

Comment: It does seem more promising. But I get kind of a opposite result: 
I know that for each $ca+v_0$ there is $ca'+v_0$ s.t. 
$||ca+v_0 - ca' - v_0|| = ||c(a-a')|| = c^2r $ 
Am I missing something?